# Parsing JSON which contains html data

Tags: html, ios, iphone, json

I  want to parse json data which contains html but there is a problem

I made a parser with this lines but always I got this error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

```
 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataoptions:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: pls show ur json which contains html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the incoming `JSON` object.  You will need to encode that `HTML` in your web-service (whatever that may be).  You should be able to see the issue when you run your `JSON` through a validator like [JSONViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) or [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com).